# How to remove all entries of a number conditionally in SQL

Tags: sql

Consider the following schema:
Suppliers (sid: integer, sname: string, address: string) 
, Parts (pid: integer, pname: string, color: string)
, and Catalog (sid: integer, pid: integer, cost: real)

The Catalog relation lists the prices charged for parts by suppliers.

Find the sids of suppliers who supply only red parts.

So I know I need to eventually select the catalog sid for the supplier but I don't know how to remove all instances of a supplier sid if they sell and item that isn't colored red.

Would appreciate any direction. I have been trying to do combinations of AND but can't seem to eliminate all sids that sell parts not red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppliers who sell only red parts:

```
Select distinct c.Sid
From Catalog c join Parts p 
   on p.pid = c.pid
Where p.Color = 'RED'
   and Not exists
        (Select * from Catalog 
         Where sid = c.Sid
            and pid in (Select Pid from Parts 
                        Where Color != 'RED'))
```

In English, it's pretty much exactly what you stated in the question

"Find the sids of suppliers who supply only red parts."

Which, converting the word `only` into it's two parts....  is equivalent to

"Find the sids of suppliers who supply red parts and do not supply any parts that are not red."

so....

```
Select distinct c.Sid   -- "Find the sids  of suppliers ..."
From Catalog c join Parts p  
   on p.pid = c.pid
Where p.Color = 'RED'   -- "who supply red parts ... "
   and Not exists       -- " and do not supply ..." 
        (Select * from Catalog -- "  Parts ... "
         Where sid = c.Sid       
            and pid in (Select Pid from Parts  -- " ... That are ..."
                        Where Color != 'RED')) -- " ... Not Red"
```

Comment: Would you be willing to provide a normal English description of the query? I am new to SQL and it would really help.

Comment: Sure, I'll add it to the answer above